# Is putting more than one punctuation mark in a single question grammatically allowed?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, grammatical-roles

I came across a sentence the other day which was structured along the lines of this:

> 'We trundled down the road, and suddenly, we hit a huge... deer? and it rocked and crumpled the car.'

Even after the question mark, the sentence continues.
Considering that the narrator is in first person and is having a bit of inner dialogue, would this be grammatically permissible?

Comment: I like the quomma: https://abstractitude.wordpress.com/2015/01/18/a-new-punctuation-mark-the-questioncomma/

Comment: I would usually parenthesise (?) it.

Comment: I'll just say that dialog, speech and dramatic phrasing are not in the same domain as formal grammar. In literature, words and punctuation are used to give the flavor of speech. In formal writing, all such effects are unnecessary and contrary to unambiguous communication. So, in the quoted sentence, the punctuation is fine, it suggests halting, questioning speech. It wouldn't be used in formal writing such as a scholarly scientific paper.